# Error in attempting to create a bundle within symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have installed symfony2 and i have ensured the application has been installed correctly and i am trying to create a bundle for my project and i seem to be getting this message and i have edited the composer.json manually and added the correct bundle to the file:

> Generating the bundle code: OK
>   **Checking that the bundle is autoloaded: FAILED**
>   Confirm automatic update of your Kernel [yes]? yes
>   Enabling the bundle inside the Kernel: OK
>   Confirm automatic update of the Routing [yes]? yes
>   Importing the bundle routing resource: OK

i have ensured composer has been configured correctly and i have removed previous namespaces from appkernel.php and routing.yml any help would be much appreciated.

this is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Acme": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"

    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share AppKernel.php and composer.json file content and folder tree view inside src folder ?

Comment: i managed to find a solution to this as i created a bundle manually and for some reason due to using iis 7.5 i then had to rewrite the urls and then trying in the cmd again to create a bundle and it created it. As well as this i didn't have composer installed as i was developing the app on a private network.

Comment: Ok. finally happy that you get it working :)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem while generating my first bundle. I did the following things:
1. Make sure you have Composer installed before generating a bundle.
2. If the same failure message occurs on generating bundles, then in the terminal type this in your project directory $ sudo  composer dumpautoload -o.
This will run your application.